# Postgresql: How to replace multiple substrings in a string and with regexp

Tags: postgresql, substring

Postgresql 9.4: 1 column in 1 table is a string of text representing a route of flight for an aircraft.

- The complete field consists of "Fixes" and "Routes" up to 80
  characters in total length.
- Routes and Fixes can be either 3 or 5 characters in length.
- Routes and Fixes can have the same name.
- There may be zero, one, or two Routes
- Routes are followed by a single non-zero digit or a hash.
- Routes and Fixes can be preceded or followed by a "+" or "*".
- The field may contain CR/LF or double-triple spaces which should remain.
- Each schema contains 6-20000s fields in this table
- There are nearly 1800 Route names, but generally only 40-80 per schema

Examples:

"KIND ROCKY1 STL BUM OATHE CLASH5 KDEN"

"+MEARZ7 OKK+
KIND OKK FWA MIZAR3 KDTW"

"KIND OOM OOM5 WEGEE PXV J131 LIT BYP5 KDFW"

"KIND MEARZ# OKK ECK YEE YXI N171B VALIEE***EGSS"

The task is to clean up the lazy use of the hash instead of a digit and to update the Route versions (the trailing numbers). I.e. replace-in-place the Route with the correct digit rather than the # or what might be a wrong number. So every instance of "MEARZ7" or "MEARZ#" becomes "MEARZ9" and "OOM5" becomes "OOM6" but "OOM " stays "OOM ".

Currently I have been testing this:

```
UPDATE target SET detail = 
CASE WHEN POSITION('CLASH' in detail) > 0 
      AND SUBSTRING(detail,POSITION('CLASH' in detail)+5,1) != ' ' 
      THEN REGEXP_REPLACE (detail, 'CLASH.', 'CLASH5')  
     WHEN POSITION('MEARZ' in detail) > 0 
      AND SUBSTRING(detail,POSITION('MEARZ' in detail)+5,1) != ' ' 
      THEN REGEXP_REPLACE (detail, 'MEARZ.', 'MEARZ9') 
     WHEN POSITION('OOM' in detail) > 0   
      AND SUBSTRING(detail,POSITION('OOM' in detail)+3,1) != ' '   
      THEN REGEXP_REPLACE (detail, 'OOM.', 'OOM6') 
     WHEN POSITION('ROCKY' in fsrtedtail) > 0 
      AND SUBSTRING(detail,POSITION('ROCKY' in detail)+5,1) != ' ' 
      THEN REGEXP_REPLACE (detail, 'ROCKY.', 'ROCKY1') 
ELSE detail END;
```

My logic was to:

- Find the Route name.
- Check if it's followed by a space.
- If not, replace it with the correct Route+digit

I hadn't yet attempted to avoid "+" or "* ". I was thinking I could first replace the "#" with a number, then update the Route+digit as to not worry about the # and this would eliminate the need to look for the "+" or "* ". Then I could just look for a trailing space.

The second Route (in order of the WHEN statements) does not get updated so I guess am barking up the wrong tree.

They other big obstacle is there can be 80 or more Routes in a schema so if I have to nest a statement, it's gonna be huge.

I have tried **array_to_string(array_replace(string_to_array(** but it leaves behind double quotes, commas, and curly brackets so doesn't seem feasible.

At this point I'm thinking a function is the way to go, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Please update your question to clearly show sample input and expected output.

Comment: There's four examples of input above. The last one: KIND MEARZ# OKK ECK YEE YXI N171B VALIEE *** EGSS would output as KIND MEARZ7 OKK ECK YEE YXI N171B VALIEE *** EGSS . Sorry, it didn't seem confusing to me.

Comment: It unclear to me. Could you please update your question to show expected output for every sample input. Also, formatting the input and output as "code" (indent 4 spaces) will make it much easier to read